# Create Module in JShell in Java 9

Tags: java, java-9, jshell, java-module

Just exploring new release of Java, its new module system, and playing with jshell as well. Probably my question doesn't have too much sense, but I am just curious.

So I came up with the question: Is there any way to create a module in jshell? Or module can be only created in `module-info.java`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modules cannot be created using JShell currently and it is not a [Goal of JShell](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222) either.

### **JShell Functionality**

> The JShell API will provide all of JShell's evaluation functionality.
>   The code fragments that are input to the API are referred to as
>   **`"snippets"`**. *The jshell tool will also use the JShell completion API to
>   determine when input is incomplete* (and the user must be prompted for
>   more), *when it would be complete if a semicolon were added* (in which
>   case the tool will append the semicolon) and also *how to complete
>   input when completion is requested with a tab.*

A snippet must correspond to one of the following JLS syntax productions:

- *Expression*
- *Statement*
- *ClassDeclaration*
- *InterfaceDeclaration*
- *MethodDeclaration*
- *FieldDeclaration*
- *ImportDeclaration*

**A `snippet` may not declare a package or a module**. All JShell code is placed in a *single package in an [unnamed module](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#the-unnamed-module)*. The name of the package is controlled by JShell.

***In fact trying to use a `ModuleDeclaration` within JShell is not a recognized syntax as well both evaluating directly or using the `/edit`:***

[image]

---

Yet, the following options can be made to work out effectively to make use of existing modules within JShell along with the snippet evaluations -

```
--module-path <path>  
      Specify where to find application modules

--add-modules <module>(,<module>)*
      Specify modules to resolve, or all modules on the
      module path if <module> is ALL-MODULE-PATHs
```